# Format data for a CSV item

Tags: c#, security, csv

This function formats the text in each cell of a CSV. The goal of the function is to make sure that the sequence of characters in `text` will never break the cell's partition. The correct output of this function looks like any of these:

- "foo"
- "123"
- "drop table 'chocolate'; -- this is fine, i don't care"
- `"<script>alert(""even scripts are allowed""); /\*notice the use of double double quotes here\*/</script>"`

```
protected string formatCSVCell(string text)
{
    // https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSV_Injection
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting
    // http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#FileFormat
    // https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201313/does-this-method-guarantee-that-cells-in-a-csv-will-be-correctly-partitioned
    var doubleQuote = "\"";

    text = text.Replace($"{doubleQuote}", $"{doubleQuote}{doubleQuote}"); // escape existing double quotes
    text = $"{doubleQuote}{text}{doubleQuote}"; // add double quotes around each value

    return text;
}
```

Comment: Can any of the three people who downvoted this explain their reasoning please. Please point to some objective violation of the site guidelines.

Comment: This question is [at the center of a discussion on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8927/120114)

Comment: there is some discussion about one of the close reasons, you can see the [help/on-topic] page on how to ask on-topic questions for more information

Comment: I personally don't think this question is off-topic, although a bit more context would be ideal, such as information about the input source and why this escaping is needed, and perhaps more code so we see this in its context in the code base.

Comment: The edits only focused on post formatting and changing the title of the post, other than that your description text is intact.  please do not be discouraged.

Comment: lol, this question has -4 votes. Every edit I make is removed by a member of this site, who then goes on to provide zero assistance with the actual problem. @Malachi I believe what you are replying to is a comment of mine that was removed lol. This site tries so hard to wash the hands of it's wild and out of control users but that's kind of a moot point since you can never get any help anyhow.

Comment: You have not edited this post since you posted it.  there are quite a few new questions posed on this site daily and it takes a lot more time to give meaningful reviews than it does to give answers on some Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: lol, I haven't edited it but three other users have. I appreciate you taking a second look. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now I can only see one thing that I might do differently, but it only shortens the code block a bit.

I might return the second statement, it removes an assignment to the variable, I don't like adding extra steps I don't have to.

```
protected string formatCSVCell(string text)
{
    // https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSV_Injection
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617935/is-there-a-way-to-include-commas-in-csv-columns-without-breaking-the-formatting
    // http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#FileFormat
    // https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201313/does-this-method-guarantee-that-cells-in-a-csv-will-be-correctly-partitioned
    var doubleQuote = "\"";

    text = text.Replace($"{doubleQuote}", $"{doubleQuote}{doubleQuote}"); 
    return $"{doubleQuote}{text}{doubleQuote}";
}
```

I would also remove those Comments because they are not useful to me.<sub>I realize that the urls are just for example</sub>

the reason I say they are not useful to me is because you have written good code here, it describes what it is doing to the point that if I had never looked at the code before (or haven't looked at it in years) I would still know what it is doing without the comments.

---

because it was in my head just now, and not because it is good coding practice, you could one-line this return statement and never actually assign to the input parameter.

```
protected string formatCSVCell(string text)
{
   var doubleQuote = "\"";

   return $"{doubleQuote}{text.Replace($"{doubleQuote}", $"{doubleQuote}{doubleQuote}")}{doubleQuote}";
}
```

Actually, that doesn't look *as bad* as I thought it was going to.  Please keep in mind that I have not tested this One Liner.